# How to decode response from Glucose Measurement Characteristic (Bluetooth)

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, base64, react-native-ble-plx

I have an react-native application and im trying to get Glucose Measurements from Accu-Chek Guide device.

I have limited knowledge on BLE and this stackoverflow question helped me a lot to understand bluetooth and retrieving glucose measurements.
[Reading from a Notify Characteristic (Ionic - Bluetooth)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45029498/13002755)

so, what im doing in my code:

1, connect to BLE Peripheral 
2, monitor characteristic `Glucose Feature` & `Record Access Control Point` 
3, send `0x0101 (Report stored records | All records)` to `Record Access Control Point` 
4, decode response

So far i have 1-3 working but i dont know how to decode the response from Glucose Feature:

Notification response of `Glucose Measurement`

> [27, 4, 0, 195, 164, 7, 7, 14, 11, 6, 5, 90, 2, 119, 194, 176, 195, 184, 0, 0]

Notification of `Record Access Control Point`

> [6, 0, 1, 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming this is the Bluetooth SIG adopted profile of Continuous Glucose Monitoring Service (CGMS) the specification of which is available from:

https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

Looking at the XML for the `Glucose Measurement` characteristic, gives more detail on how the data is structured.

https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.glucose_measurement.xml

There will be a little bit of work to do to unpack the data.

For example, the first byte stores the information for the first field named `flags`. However you need to look at the first 5 bits for those various flags.

The next field is "Sequence Number" which is a `uint16` so will take two bytes. Worth noting here that Bluetooth typically uses [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Next is the `Base Time` field which refers to https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Characteristics/org.bluetooth.characteristic.date_time.xml which will take the next 7 bytes.

Because some of the 9 fields in the characteristic take more than one byte, this is why you are seeing 20 bytes for the 9 fields.

Comment: thanks for your reply @ukBaz
i checked glucose related services for `Accu-Chek guide` and it only supports `Glucose` service `0x1808`. on my original question, i meant to say `Glucose Measurement` instead of `Glucose Feature`. im assuming the base64 decoded value from `Glucose Measurement` characteristic should correspond to the fields of `XML for Glucose Measurement`? if so, im receiving array w/ 20 elements instead of 9.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more detail on how to unpack the 20 bytes you are receiving for the 9 fields.

Comment: I have decoded responses from Glucose Measurement successfully. But how to get Glucose Measurement Context responses then? I have already subscribed to this characteristic together with Glucose Measurement  & RACP.

Do I need to write another request to RACP?

Comment: The `Glucose Measurement Context` characteristic is a variable-length structure which is detailed in the [GATT Specification Supplement 5](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-5/) document. If you need more information it should be a new question.

Comment: All those XML resources are not available any more. Do you know where the information moved to or if there is any alternative?

Comment: The Bluetooth SIG now document this in the `GATT Specification Supplement` document at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/. The format is quite different but the information should be in there.

Comment: @programmerdreamer Can you help me with decoding the GLucose measurement?